# Get data from Json and rendering in html(with bootstrap) ajax call and mustache template

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, templates, mustache

I have my site built with bootstrap. I want to create a div with data stored in a JSON file and rendering with mustache. I have the script inside the HTML for mustache template:

```
<script id="plutos" type="text/template">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4">
    <h3 class="text-center" >{{title}}</h3>
    <img src="{{picture}}" style="width:100%">
    <p class="text-justify" class="text-center">{{plot}}</p>
    <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs red">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-thumbs-up"></i> 
    </button>
  </div>
</script>
```

My articles.json Data storage with array

```
[{
  "title": "Casa",
  "picture": "img/portfolio/cabin.png",
  "plot": "Per casa si intende una qualunque struttura utilizzata dagli esseri umani per ripararsi dagli agenti atmosferici. Essa generalmente ospita uno o più nuclei familiari e talvolta anche animali.",
  "like": false
}, 
// ...
```

I have this JS for the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "articles.json",
}).done(function( msg ) {
  var template = $('#plutos').html();
  var html = Mustache.to_html(template, msg);
  $('#portfolio').html(html);
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for properly including your code, but unfortunately you haven't asked a question. What doesn't work?

Comment: The render of my data into html ...i have to do a $each of my array

Answer (score 0):

Your data comes back in an array, so change this

```
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, msg);
```

to

```
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, msg[0]); // [0] -> get the first object.
```

if that works, then you can loop through the array to get each object.

---

Fwiw, I'm used to an different version that uses `render`:

```
var html = Mustache.render(template, msg);
```